# How to replicate rows of a dataframe a fixed number of times?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replicate rows of a dataframe as to prepare for the adding of a column. The dataframe contains *years* column and I want to add a fixed column of *months*. The idea is to replicate each same year rows exactly 12 times then add a fixed value column (1-12).
my code is the following:

```
        all_years = dataframe["Year"].unique().tolist()
        new_dataset = pd.DataFrame()
        for idx, year in enumerate(all_years):
            rows_dataframe = pd.concat(
                [dataframe.where(dataframe["Year"] == year).dropna()] * 12,
                ignore_index=True)
            new_dataset = pd.concat([rows_dataframe, new_dataset], ignore_index=True)
```

The results are correct, but can I avoid the for loop here, and implement this in a more "pandas-ic" way?

EDIT: expected results for one value of years (here 2012) is: (to note that months column is not added through my code, but added it to show the final output)

```
+-------+--------+---------+
| Years | Months | SomeCol |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2011  | 12     | val1    |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2012  | 1      | val1    |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2012  | 2      | val1    |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2012  | 3      | val1    |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2012  | 4      | val1    |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2012  | 5      | ...     |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2012  | 6      | ...     |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2012  | 7      |   val1  |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2012  | 8      | val1    |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2012  | 9      | val1    |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2012  | 10     |         |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2012  | 11     |         |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2012  | 12     |         |
+-------+--------+---------+
| 2013  | 1      | ...     |
+-------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: can you show the final output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `groupby`. I am assuming each year occurs only once in your data frame:

```
new_dataset = dataframe.groupby("Year").apply(lambda x: pd.concat([x] * 12)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or just repeat and sort the values:

```
new_dataset = pd.concat([dataframe] * 12).sort_values("Year").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of pd.DataFrame.loc and pd.Index.repeat:

```
dataframe = dataframe.loc[dataframe.index.repeat(12)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df.assign(month=[range(12)]*len(df)).explode('month').drop('month', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should replicate each row for each year 12 times, and add a fixed column of months to each row. Instead of dropping NaN values with dropna(), I used a boolean indexing approach.

```
import pandas as pd

# unique() returns a NumPy array     
all_years = dataframe["Year"].unique()
    
new_dataset = pd.DataFrame()

for year in all_years:
    # boolean indexing                
    rows_dataframe = dataframe[dataframe["Year"] == year]
    
    repeated_rows = pd.concat([rows_dataframe] * 12, ignore_index=True)
    repeated_rows["Month"] = range(1, 13)
    new_dataset = new_dataset.append(repeated_rows, ignore_index=True)
                                                      
print(new_dataset)
```

Created a new DataFrame by repeating each row 12 times using
`pd.concat([rows_dataframe] * 12, ignore_index=True)`, and then adding a fixed column of months
`repeated_rows["Month"] = range(1, 13)`.
Lastly, append the repeated rows to the new dataset `new_dataset.append(repeated_rows, ignore_index=True)`.